# Writing stringstream contents into ofstream

Tags: c++, stl, parameters, stringstream, ofstream

I'm currently using `std::ofstream` as follows:

```
std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(output_file);
```

Then I attempt to pass a `std::stringstream` object to `outFile` as follows:

```
GetHolesResults(..., std::ofstream &outFile){
  float x = 1234;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << x << std::endl;
  outFile << ss;
}
```

Now my `outFile` contains nothing but garbage: "0012E708" repeated all over.

In `GetHolesResults` I can write

```
outFile << "Foo" << std:endl;
```

and it will output correctly in `outFile`.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you rephrase the title to something in the line of: 'writting stringstream contents into ofstream' (or ostream for what matters)

Comment: Eric, you should mark Johannes' answer as accepted so that I can delete mine (which is clearly worse than his approach)

Comment: Ok, done. But back in the days, I used your solution =)

Comment: :) Someone upvoted my answer today, which might indicate that they chose a less-than-perfect solution when a better one was available.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can do this, which doesn't need to create the string. It makes the output stream read out the contents of the stream on the right side (usable with any streams).

```cpp
outFile << ss.rdbuf();
```

Comment: I'm curious: why this solution works with `std::stringstream` but not with `std::ostringstream`? In the second case I am getting an empty file.

Comment: @JaviV because you can [only write](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) to `std::oANYSTREAM` and only read from `std::iANYSTREAM`. There will be no sense for `output_stream` if it would have also `read` operations. If you need both just use `std::ANYSTREAM` and you are home :)

Comment: I'm backing here after upvoting years ago. Its a bit weird that the compiler does not warning about call rdbuf from ostringstream

Answer (score 27):

If you are using `std::ostringstream` and wondering why nothing get written with `ss.rdbuf()` then use `.str()` function.

```
outFile << oStream.str();
```

Comment: your answer led me to the following realization: to get a `char` array from `ss`, you can do `ss.str().c_str()`.  (just posting here for the benefit of newbies who stumble on this in the future.)

Comment: @Digital_Reality, thanks! nothing was getting written when i used rdbuff. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

When passing a stringstream rdbuf to a stream newlines are not translated.  The input text can contain `\n` so find replace won't work.  The old code wrote to an fstream and switching it to a stringstream losses the endl translation.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer because you haven't told how to write a std::stringstream to a std::ofstream

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather write `ss.str();` instead of `ss.rdbuf();` (and use a stringstream).

If you use `ss.rdbuf()` the format-flags of `outFile` will be reset rendering your code non-reusable.
I.e., the caller of `GetHolesResults(..., std::ofstream &outFile)` might want to write something like this to display the result in a table:

```
outFile << std::setw(12) << GetHolesResults ...
```

...and wonder why the width is ignored.