# ostringstream breaks cout?

Tags: c++, ostringstream

I want to output the content of a `ostringstream` to some other stream (for example `std::cout`). I know that I can use `std::ostringstream::str()` but I assume it has an overhead on copying the stream contents to a string and then further to the other stream. I found that I could use `std::ostringstream::rdbuf()` ([Comment suggesting that has 25 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/324975/1781497)). But it breaks `std::cout` as is shown in the output of the test program below. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "some data" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss.str();
    std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << std::cout  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

```
0x6013b8
start
some data
0
```

Comment: Use `str()` as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `rdbuf()` buffer for an `ostringstream` is, as you might expect from the name, *write only* (the `ostringstream` returns the string through the `str()` method). You can't read the data back out of it through the buffer pointer.

Change your `ostringstream` to `stringstream` and it should work fine.